# Can't install rpi imager

Tags: software-installation, raspberrypi

I am trying to install rpi imager on my laptop to configure my new rapsberry, but when I try to, it says "you need to use "dpkg -- configure -a" to correct the problem.
I don't know how to properly use the command, could someone help me ?
Thanks !

edit : I am running on Ubuntu, I am not very used to it, so where should I find the exact ditribution ?

Comment: You've not provided any OS & release details; are you using Ubuntu Server? Ubuntu Core, what release of that product or is it something else?  The command you mention is not run on all OSes so you should be specific.\

Comment: For Ubuntu Try opening terminal and paste: `dpkg -- configure -a`.